# Business located in USA does it need to be PCI and SCA compliant?

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card, payment-gateway

The business is located in the US. But:

1. Has European customers who put a transaction via a custom-built
2. shopping cart Sells via tradeshow in Europe or Asia in person Could
3. Customers send credit cards via phone

Question: is the business supposed to be both PCI and SCA compliant (Europe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most jurisdictions, PCI is not law, it is an industry-enforced security standard. If you take card payments from any of the payment card systems (which is essentially all of the major credit card systems, including but not limited to Visa, MasterCard, American Express, Discover and JCB), you have to be PCI compliant. It does not matter where you or your customer resides, it does not matter what kind of shop you are, and it doesn't matter how you capture the card detail, if you take cards, you are in scope of PCI compliance.

If you are not PCI compliant and your merchant account/payment terminal is found to be involved in a chargeback or fraud, you'll be liable for the chargeback/fraud. You'll also be in breach of contract with your acquiring bank/payment processor, and your bank may impose fines/penalties on your merchant accounts, or impose higher fees on you, or they may terminate your ability to take card payments. They may also put you in blacklist with other banks, which can make it difficult/impossible for you or your business to get a merchant account with any other banks.

In some countries, PCI compliance is also legally imposed, in which case the government or private citizens may also file additional criminal or civil lawsuits against you.

PCI compliance have different levels. If you're a small merchant with low volume of transaction and you used the service of a compliant payment processor, you may able to use self assessment questionnaire (SAQ) to evaluate your PCI compliance which can significantly reduce the burden of compliance. You can complete these questionnaires yourself without external auditors, you'll still be responsible for completing it correctly. If you're a higher volume merchant, you'll need to take higher level of compliance, and this will usually involve a PCI auditor.

I don't know what you meant by SCA, but from a quick Google search, it doesn't seem to be a security related, and therefore off topic here.